# Is there any way to mimic class-instance-variable concept from Ruby in Java?

Tags: java, oop

Suppose I have an Animal class, and two of its sub-classes namely Dog & Cat. I want to keep counts of instances of Dog and Cat classes (e.g. {Dog: 3, Cat: 1}).

```
class Animal{
  static int instances = 0;
  public Animal(){
    instances++;
  }
}
```

I can use `Animal.instances` to get the count of all the animals. However, I want to get the counts separately for each type of animal. How can I achieve this without repeating the same code in constructors of all the sub-classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on statics or on [reflexively checking the class name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54552864/1898563).

The best way to solve this problem is to defer responsibility for creating the objects to a factory:

```
interface AnimalFactory<T extends Animal>
{
    T create();
}

interface CountingAnimalFactory<T extends Animal> extends AnimalFactory<T>
{
    int numberOfAnimals();
}

public class CountingDogFactory implements CountingAnimalFactory<Dog>
{
    private int numberOfDogs;

    public Dog create() {
        numberOfDogs++;
        return new Dog();
    }

    public int numberOfAnimals() {
         return numberOfDogs;
    }
}
```

You can make the constructors for `Dog` and `Cat` package-private to enforce that they are instantiated via the factory.

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a map:

```
class Animal {

    static Map<String, Long> counts = new HashMap<>();

    public Animal() {
        counts.compute(this.getClass().getName(), 
                (s, old) -> old == null ? 1 : old + 1);
    }
}
```

If you foresee a race condition, then you should probably make `counts` a `ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: Ok for all the answers above, but don't forget, that if you redefine the no arg constructor you will have to do:

    class Cat extends Animal {
     public Cat(Arg arg){
      super();
     }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help:

```
class Animal {
    static Map<Class, Integer> instances = new HashMap<>();

    public Animal() {
        if (instances.get(this.getClass()) == null)
            instances.put(this.getClass(), 0);
        instances.put(this.getClass(), instances.get(this.getClass()) + 1);
    }
}
```

Now if you want to get the number of Cats use `instances.get(Cat.class)`.